# Create phpBB3 account automatically based on facebook login

Tags: facebook, oauth, phpbb, phpbb3

I'm using phpBB3.1 with the new option to link your forum account with your facebook account. Once an account is linked, you could log-in to to the forum with facebook if you liked.

But how would I automate the creation of a forum account using facebook data when someone tries to log-in with an unlinked facebook account?

By adding this to **includes\ucp\ucp_login_link.php**, I can add a new user to the database:

```
$user_row = array(
    'username'              => 'New Facebook User',
    'user_password'         => phpbb_hash('random password'),
    'user_email'            => 'random@email.com',
    'group_id'              => 4,
    'user_type'             => 0,
);

$user_id = user_add($user_row);
```

But how do I populate the fields with the facebook data and link it to the newly created forum account? Thanks! Looking for a phpBB3 expert here :/

Comment: Are you using v3.1 on a live site? Its still in beta yet and not recommended for production use as there is still work to do on bug fixes etc

Answer (score 0):

Someone would need to create an extension to allow FB logins. No such extension is currently available. It would introduce a number of issues because the user would still have to register with the forum and go through its registration process.

You don't want to hack the phpBB 3.1 base code itself because when you upgrade phpBB you will potentially overwrite your file changes.